# разные способы быстрой генерации и сохранение md5 хешей

Tags: php, хеширование, md5

Ищу разные способы быстрой генерации и сохранение `md5` хешей, при использование `php` генерация идет медленно (50мб генерируется в хеши за 30 мин).

Насколько быстро можно генерировать `md5` другими способами? Есть уже готовые программы?

Comment: Не совсем понятно - а что за "генерируются"? md5 - вычисляет hash от строки. Вам просто нужны случайные последовательности символов, которые не зависят ни от чего? Или у Вас есть куча мелких строк (типа пароли пользователей) и Вам нужно получить от них хеши? Или Вам требуется брать кучу хешей от больших файлов? Или вообще что-то другое?

Comment: Чем именно в php вы генерите MD5 и для какого объекта ? Только что замерял скорость функции php http://php.net/manual/ru/function.md5-file.php 700Mb файл посчитала,за 2.5 секунды

Comment: есть файл, в нем пароли пользователей , примерно так:
pass3
psdoo3
Нужно каждый пароль зашифровать в md5  и сохранить в файлик, с помощью пхп медленно.

Comment: Так может у вас операции записи в файл медленные, а не генерация хешей.

Comment: @u_mulder а как увеличить тогда?